# Supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php

```
$file = fopen("RU/6_RU.html","w+");
fputs ($file, str_replace($search, $replace,$NTV));
fclose ($file);
```

Вылетает ошибка

```
Warning: fopen(RU/6_RU.html) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Warning: fputs(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

и? У вас черным по белому ннаписано, что premission denied со всеми вытекающими not valid resource, который в данном случае null 
права на файл правильные выставьте

зыж видимо следующий вопрос будет "на какой файл" -- на тот, который открываете

ззыж а следующий -- "а какие права правильные" -- read и write, раз вы в него еще и писать собираетесь.

зззыж если файла несуществует, то значит прав на директорию RU нет, тогда нужно на нее выставить права как минимум write, но лучше и read и x